# Call list of timeseries objects in a function in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to forecast a rate for my timeseries data. I have multiple timeseries objects in a list and I want to call each of them in a function which will return the forecast output.

When I pass individual timeseries to the function, I get the correct output. But when I pass the list, the output goes wrong.

```
my.meta.function <- function(my.data){
  df.name <- my.data
  length(df.name)
  train <- head(df.name, 0.77 * length(df.name))
  test <- tail(df.name, 0.23 * length(df.name))

  fit <- arima(train, c(1, 1, 0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 0), period = 12), method ="ML")
  fcast <- forecast(fit, h=12)

  plot(fcast, main = 'Forecasts from ARIMA')
  lines(test, col="red")
    legend("topleft",lty=1,bty = "n",col=c("red","blue"),c("testData","Prediction"))
  return(fit)
  }
```

```
list1 = list(a_ts=ts(measure[measure$Acronym == "a",][,3],start = c(2016,5),frequency = 12),
b_ts=ts(measure[measure$Acronym == "b",][,3],start = c(2016,5),frequency = 12),
c_ts=ts(measure[measure$Acronym == "c",][,3],start = c(2016,5),frequency = 12)
)
```

Comment: I know this is obvious, but did you try to iterate over all the elements of the list with `lapply` or `loop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can apply a function to a list in R. Just make sure your function accepts the individual element in the list as the input.

With lapply in base R.

```
lapply(list, my.meta.function)
```

The tidyverse way is using purrr::map.

```
map(list, ~my.meta.function(.))
```

These will both output a list where each element is the result of the function.

Comment: I used lapply and map but it plots the same output for all the timeseries in the list.